# Storing Answers From Functions into a Vector in R

Tags: r, function, vector, while-loop, factorial

I was prompted a question and am ever so close to solving what I need. The question is as follows-

"Write a while loop that computes and stores as a new object, the factorial of any non-negative integer mynum by decrementing mynum by 1 at each repetition of the braced code."

Another factor was that if 0 or 1 was entered, the output would be 1.

The code that I wrote as follows-

```
factorialcalc <- function(i){
  factorial <- 1
  if(i==0 | i==1){
    factorial <- 1
  } else{
    while(i >= 1){
      factorial <- factorial * i
      i <- i-1
    }
  }
  return (factorial)
}
```

with inputs-

```
mynum <- 5
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

and output-

```
[1] 120
```

You may be wondering, "your code works perfect, so what's the issue?"
My issue lies in the part of the question that says "computes AND stores."

How can I modify my code to put the answers of factorialcalc into a vector?

Example-
I input

```
mynum <- 5
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

and

```
mynum <- 3
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

and

```
mynum <- 4
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

When I call this new vector, I would like to see a vector with all three of their outputs
(so almost like I made a vector c(120,6,24))

I'm thinking there's a way to add this vector somewhere in my function or while loop, but I'm not sure where. Also, please note that the answer must contain a loop like in my code.

Comment: if you pass your arguments as a vector, the output will automatically be a vector. ```mynum <- c(5, 4, 3)``` then ```factorialcalc(mynum)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Option 1.

**"Vectorize" your function**

```
# simply wrap the whole thing in Vectorize()
Factorialcalc = Vectorize(function(i){
  factorial <- 1
  if(i==0 | i==1){
    factorial <- 1
  } else{
    while(i >= 1){
      factorial <- factorial * i
      i <- i-1
    }
  }
  return (factorial)
})
# Now when you supply it a vector, it runs on each element
> Factorialcalc(c(5, 3, 4))
[1] 120   6  24
```

#### Option 2.

**Use functions that are designed to apply a single function to multiple elements of a supplied vector.**
Using `map_dbl` from the `purrr` package, you can call:

```
map_dbl(c(5, 3, 4), factorialcalc)
```

Which supplies to your function `factorialcalc` each element in `vector` and concatenates each result before returning a vector.

Using `base R` you can simply use the `apply`-family functions:

```
sapply(c(5, 3, 4), factorialcalc)
```

and get the same result.

**Example**

```
> map_dbl(c(5, 3, 4), factorialcalc)
[1] 120   6  24
> sapply(c(5, 3, 4), factorialcalc)
[1] 120   6  24
```

Comment: This answer helps a bunch, and is enough to answer the question. If I could take it one step further, is there a way we could create an empty vector like say ```answers <- c()``` and then using ```factorialcalc```'s return output to fill the ```answers``` vector?

Comment: If you want to program it that way, then you don't need to vectorize the function. You would loop through your digits, one by one to supply them to `factorialcalc`, and one by one place them into your output vector, `answers`. Try using `append`. Something like `answers <- c(); for (i in c(5, 3, 4)) {answers <- append(answers, factorialcalc(i))}`