# How to add Results into a Vector within a Loop in R

Tags: r, function, if-statement, while-loop, factorial

I was prompted a question and am ever so close to solving what I need. The question is as follows-

"Write a while loop that computes and stores as a new object, the factorial of any non-negative integer mynum by decrementing mynum by 1 at each repetition of the braced code."

Another factor was that if 0 or 1 was entered, the output would be 1.

The code that I wrote as follows-

```
factorialcalc <- function(i){
  factorial <- 1
  if(i==0 | i==1){
    factorial <- 1
  } else{
    while(i >= 1){
      factorial <- factorial * i
      i <- i-1
    }
  }
  return (factorial)
}
```

with inputs-

```
mynum <- 5
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

and output-

```
[1] 120
```

You may be wondering, "your code works perfect, so what's the issue?"
My issue lies in the part of the question that says "computes AND stores."

How can I modify my code to put the answers of factorialcalc into a vector?

Example-
I input

```
mynum <- 5
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

and

```
mynum <- 3
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

and

```
mynum <- 4
factorialcalc(mynum)
```

When I call this new vector, I would like to see a vector with all three of their outputs
(so almost like I made a vector c(120,6,24))

I'm thinking there's a way to add this vector somewhere in my function or while loop, but I'm not sure where. Also, please note that the answer must contain a loop like in my code.

The answer I would be looking for would have an empty vector say `answers <- c()`, and every time I were to run the function `factorialcalc`, during the function, I would add the return results from `factorial` into this new `answers` vector.

I've tried putting in something like this-

```
factorialcalc <- function(i){
  factorial <- 1
  answers <- c()
  answers[i] <- answers[factorial]
  if(i==0 | i==1){
    factorial <- 1
  } else{
    while(i >= 1){
      factorial <- factorial * i
      i <- i-1
    }
  }
  return (factorial)
}
```

This doesn't seem to work, but I think the idea is there.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: If you initialize an empty vector before a `for` loop, you can simply append a new value within the loop.  e.g. `myvec <- numeric(); for... myvec <- c(myvec, newval)...` The `length` my `myvec` will grow with each iteration of the loop.

Comment: Is this only for a ```for``` loop? The question that was given to me was to do this with a ```while``` loop

Comment: Use can use the method with any loop. You can also use the method to augment a list of objects.  e.g. create the list: `mylist <- list()` and augment the list index inside a loop: `mylist[[i]] <- newdf` where `i` is an integer loop index value.

Comment: Is this question any different than your previous question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65057122/storing-answers-from-functions-into-a-vector-in-r ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution that illustrates how to build a vector of results for a factorial function. We use the `testthat` package to build unit tests for the function.

Rather than iterating from `i` down to 1, we iterate from 2 to `i`, using the `j-1` value in the output vector to multiply by the current number in the `for()` loop.

We also include error checking at the top of the function. Since R does not have a way to directly validate a numeric vector as an integer / whole number, we compare the absolute value of the input minus its rounded value to machine precision and stop if the comparison fails.

```
factorial <- function(i){
     # return a vector of factorial values from 1 to i, where
     # i represents the i-th value in the factorial series 
     
     # first, validate the input 
     if(!is.numeric(i)) stop("i must be a whole number")
     if(!(abs(i - round(i)) < .Machine$double.eps^0.5)) stop("i must be a whole number")
     if (i < 0) stop("i must be a whole number")

     # now, process based on value of i 
     if (i %in% c(0,1)) return(1)
     resultVector <- 1
     # if we get here, i is greater than 1
     for(j in 2:i) resultVector <- c(resultVector,resultVector[j-1]*j)
     resultVector
}
```

We test the function with a variety of tests, ranging from invalid input handling to confirming the output of the function with known values. We also compare the length of the output vector to the input value of `i`.

```
library(testthat)
test_that("Factorial function works",{
     expect_error(factorial(-3),"i must be a whole number",ignore.case=TRUE)
     expect_equal(1,factorial(0))
     expect_equal(1,factorial(1))
     expect_equal(c(1,2),factorial(2))
     expect_equal(c(1,2,6),factorial(3))
     expect_equal(c(1,2,6,24),factorial(4))
     expect_equal(c(1,2,6,24,120),factorial(5))
     expect_equal(5,length(factorial(5))) # test that length matches input i
     expect_error(factorial(3.1),"i must be a whole number",ignore.case=TRUE)
     expect_error(factorial("zzz"),"i must be a whole number",ignore.case=TRUE)
     
     
})
```

...and the test results:

```
==> Testing R file using 'testthat'

✓ |  OK F W S | Context
✓ |  10       | factorial

══ Results ═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
Duration: 0.2 s

OK:       10
Failed:   0
Warnings: 0
Skipped:  0

Test complete
```

Finally, we run the function multiple times to illustrate its output:

```
> lapply(1:8,factorial)
[[1]]
[1] 1

[[2]]
[1] 1 2

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 6

[[4]]
[1]  1  2  6 24

[[5]]
[1]   1   2   6  24 120

[[6]]
[1]   1   2   6  24 120 720

[[7]]
[1]    1    2    6   24  120  720 5040

[[8]]
[1]     1     2     6    24   120   720  5040 40320
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Reduce` first as replacement of your method:

```r
Reduce(`*`, 1:5)
# [1] 120
```

To extend incrementally, pass a sequence with `Reduce` inside an apply function (only `mapply` needs adjustment due to multiple elements):

```r
factorialcalc <- function(i) Reduce(`*`, 1:i)
    
sapply(1:5, factorialcalc)
# [1]   1   2   6  24 120

vapply(1:5, factorialcalc, integer(1))
# [1]   1   2   6  24 120

tapply(1:5, 1:5, factorialcalc)
#   1   2   3   4   5 
#   1   2   6  24 120 
    
factorialcalc <- function(i,j) Reduce(`*`, i:j)
mapply(factorialcalc, 1, 1:5)
# [1]   1   2   6  24 120
```